# Ordinate Div by H1 name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to sort in alphabetical order of the box using the h1 tag.

This is ​​the code:

```
<div id="test">

<div class="box">
       <div class="internalBox">
            <h1><a href="http://www.example-t.it">third</a></h1>
           <p>Sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
       <div class="internalBox">
            <h1><a href="http://www.example-f.it">first</a></h1>
           <p>Sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</p>
    </div>

   ....
</div>

<script>
    $( ".box h1", "#test" ).sort(function( a, b ) {
        return $( a ).parents('.box').html() > $( b ).parents('.box').html(); 

    }).appendTo( "#test" );
</script>
```

and here the example

http://jsfiddle.net/5Fap4/

How can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$(".box").sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).find("h1").text() > $(b).find("h1").text() ? 1 : -1; 
}).appendTo( "#test" );
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dS7PC/)